# 2D Pattern in recursive digit sum of consecutive x^n

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations

Take the recursive decimal digit sum of consecutive binary numbers $2^n$ as $n \to \infty$. You'll see something like this:

```
n   2^n (recursive) sum of digits
-----------------------------------------
1   2   2
2   4   4
3   8   8
4   16  7
5   32  5
6   64  1
7   128 2 (1+2+8=11), (1+1=2)
8   256 4
9   512 8
10  1024    7
11  2048    5
12  4096    1
13  8192    2
14  16384   4
15  32768   8
16  65536   7
17  131072  5
```

Notice the cycle $1,2,4,8,7,5$ and exclusion of $3,6,9$? No such cycle for $3$ ($3^1=3$, rest is a $9$) but I see one for $5 $ $(1,5,7,8,4,2) $ and haven't checked any higher.

I'm curious if there's something (theorem/result) in number theory explains such recursive sum of digit cycles, why do they exist and for some (prime?) numbers alone?

*** EDIT ****:
I just ran a quick computation of this recursive-sum-of-digits of $x^n$ for $x = 10,000$ and $n = 25$ and see a general pattern. The sequence repeats for every 9th x:

```
1, Sequence: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
2, Sequence: 1,2,4,8,7,5,1,2,4,8,7,5,1,2,4,8,7,5,1,2,4,8,7,5,1
3, Sequence: 1,3,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9
4, Sequence: 1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1
5, Sequence: 1,5,7,8,4,2,1,5,7,8,4,2,1,5,7,8,4,2,1,5,7,8,4,2,1
6, Sequence: 1,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9
7, Sequence: 1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1
8, Sequence: 1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1
9, Sequence: 1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9
10, Sequence: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
11, Sequence: 1,2,4,8,7,5,1,2,4,8,7,5,1,2,4,8,7,5,1,2,4,8,7,5,1
12, Sequence: 1,3,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9
13, Sequence: 1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1,4,7,1
14, Sequence: 1,5,7,8,4,2,1,5,7,8,4,2,1,5,7,8,4,2,1,5,7,8,4,2,1
15, Sequence: 1,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9
16, Sequence: 1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1,7,4,1
17, Sequence: 1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1,8,1
18, Sequence: 1,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9
19, Sequence: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
20, Sequence: 1,2,4,8,7,5,1,2,4,8,7,5,1,2,4,8,7,5,1,2,4,8,7,5,1
```

Notice that there are vertical patterns as well for every consecutive 9th n. Or rather the matrix below repeats vertically and horizontally(with 9's replacing 3,6 for n > 2, skipping 1 repeat entirely):

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1
1,2,4,8,7,5,1, 2
1,3,9,9,9,9,9, 9 (horizontal repeat start, 9 replacement)
1,4,7,1,4,7,1, 4
1,5,7,8,4,2,1, 5
1,6,9,9,9,9,9, 9
1,7,4,1,7,4,1, 7
1,8,1,8,1,8,1, 8
1,9,9,9,9,9,9, 9
```

Comment: The digital root(sum of the sum of the sum...of the sum of digits) of $n$ in base $b+1$ is $n \pmod b$. Now prove that $x^k\pmod b$ is eventually periodic in $k$ for all integers $x,b$

Answer (score 0):

The digital sum of $m$ is $m \pmod 9$, except that if $m$ is divisible by $9$ you get $9$, not zero.  This is the basis of the classic [divisibility rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) for $9$.  Now once you note the cycle $1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 5, 1$ you will repeat.  For other bases you have the same behavior.